# Migration to MobileFirst

Tags: migration, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I do migration of worklight projects to mobilefirst.
When I open project created in worklight version 6.2 in new mobilefirst studio I see this project always as closed in eclipse. When I try to open it then I get this error:

```
!ENTRY com.worklight.studio.plugin 4 0 2015-02-17 13:09:10.550
!MESSAGE FWLPL0019E: Migrating the HiPerForms project from version     6.2.0.01.20141002-2218 to version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357 has failed because     org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.; FWLPL0019E: Migrating the HiPerForms project from version 6.2.0.01.20141002-2218 to version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357 has failed because org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
!STACK 0 com.worklight.upgrader.UpgradeEngineException: FWLPL0019E: Migrating the HiPerForms project from version 6.2.0.01.20141002-2218 to version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357 has failed because org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:271)
at com.worklight.studio.plugin.upgrader.WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

When I delete .settings folder of the project I can open the project in eclipse but then after restarting eclipse I have again closed project.

Any idea what's it could be?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you provide the project, or a sample project, showing this error so that it could be debugged?

Comment: I too get a similar issue on migration, but the error is different.   Migrating to Cordova 3.7.0 for ipad - file ipad is modified.Migrator class com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.ios.AppCordova361IPadClassesUpgrader has failed Migrating the DemoApp project from version 6.2.0.00.20140724-2139 to version 6.3.0.00.20150214-1702 has failed because java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: /Users/sen/Documents/MobileFirst-0/DemoApp/apps/Demo101/ipad/native/CordovaLib/Classes/UIDevice+Extensions.m

Comment: This is not helpful. Are you able to provide a Worklight 6.2 project that this can be reproduced with?

Comment: It's  big project. I will extract it for you for test as soon as I can. Thank you.

Comment: Does not need to your Your project. If you can re-create it in a smaller-scale app it would be better.

Comment: I don't have this issue in the "smaller-scale" app. I guess something project-related.

Comment: @NataliyaLeLoup, Any luck with supplying something? We cannot progress with this question otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is likely a migration error and since you cannot provide the project's source code here, my suggestion for you is to open an IBM support ticket (PMR) and provide your source code there so that the bug could be debugged and resolved.

Edit: a smaller project was provided in the comments to this answer. The error was reproduced and the bug was found and will be fixed. See below for a workaround.  You can open a PMR in order to receive a fixed Studio build.

**Workaround**
To workaround it, remove the `proxy` node from adapter XML file and try to migrate. Then, add it back after migration completes.

Comment: Hi. Sorry didn't reply for a while. Here is the link to the repository with project. https://github.com/nataliyaleloup/MFMigration  I extracted it and still cannot  open in eclipse. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Comment: The link is missing from your comment.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Reproduced. The development team is taking a look at it - per my answer, if you need a fix for it, you'll to open a PMR. As for a workaround, I'll edit my answer if it will be found.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "proxy" element? proxy settings? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: In your adapter XML, there is a proxy node.